# Не могу разобраться, почему не выполняется заданное условие

Tags: python, python-3.x

В работе код просто игнорирует условие обозначенное в 21 строке, т.е. в строке

```
elif y < a < b < x:
```

Заданные параметры:

> ```
> N: 53  
> M: 3  
> x: 2  
> y: 0
> ```

Код программы:

```
N = int(input())
M = int(input())
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
if M > N:
    a = (N - x)
    b = (M - y)
    if a < y < x < b:
        print (a)
    elif y < a < b < x:
        print (y)
    elif b < y < a < x:
        print (b)
    else:
        print (x)
else:
    a = (M - x)
    b = (N - y)
    if a < y < x < b:
        print (a)
    elif y < a < b < x:
        print (y)
    elif b < y < a < x:
        print (b)
    else:
        print (x)
```

(Этот код тоже на [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/NRfSnKTf).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что не выполняется условие `b < x`.

Выражение `A < B < C` равносильно `A < B and B < C`.

Для лучшей отладки вашего кода могу посоветовать воспользоваться [визуализатором](http://pythontutor.ru/visualizer/), это поможет для самых простых проектов.

Comment: >`Выражение A < B < C равносильно A < B and B < C.` - а не `(результат A < B) < C`?

Comment: Первое. Результат `A < B` может быть либо `True`, либо `False`, что для Питона 3.x равносильно `1` и `0`. Но данная запись просто позволяет сократить условие, дабы не множить `and`ы

Comment: Проверил сам, да, действительно. Не знал, что питон так умеет. Не подскажете, где конкретно можно почитать про это?

Comment: Конкретно про это не могу сказать, но вы можете найти литературу по Питону здесь proglib.io/p/python-from-newbie-to-professional.
Я бы советовал Марка Лутца "Изучаем Питон" 4-е издание

Comment: @МихаилМуругов [в официальной документации](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

Comment: @extrn Спасибо!